# Define an expression according to the last record

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011, fetchxml

I've created a custom report in Fetch XML with an expression calculating the time spent on each incident according to a date range parameter. 
No problem here to create the expression but this one should only concern the last contract record (I still need the previous ones to appear on the report though). Is there any way to do that?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the [function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159673%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) for [Last](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155794%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) value within a certain scope? E.g.

```
=Last(Fields!ProductNumber.Value, "Category")
```

Comment: With a little bit of work on my expression, that did the trick, thanks !!